# How to count tags with tag name of a user in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a Post Model like below and I am using `django-taggit`

```
class Post(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  post = models.TextField()
  tags = TaggableManager()

>>>p1 = Post(user='user1', post='Some description', tags="python, java, js")
>>>p1.save()
>>>p2 = Post(user='user2', post='Some description', tags="c, java, js")
>>>p2.save()
>>>p3 = Post(user='user1', post='Some description', tags="c, js, python")
>>>p3.save()
```

Now I want to get the tags and tag count of each user is tagged like below

```
{
  'user1': {'python':2, 'java':1, 'js':2, 'c':1}, 
  'user2': {'c':1,'java':1,'js':1}
}
```

I tried with annotate, aggregation but not able write the exact query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["python"]).count()
```

Comment: This won't work, I should able to retrieve all tags and related count of each tag of a user. Your answer will return only tag count and it's not grouped by all tags.